# How to install root certificate inside iOS app, so it will be trusted when open URL from UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ssl, uiwebview

I have iOS app in which I need to use UIWebView to open web page which uses SSL Certificate which is not issued by Trusted Authority. I got error.

I can manually install SSL certificate, but I need to do this on every client device, which is not an option, so I need to install the root certificate from code.

But I don't know how to do that. I google but in most cases it is about importing provisioning certificates.

Any guidance? I need just a direction where to search.

I read that there is a SSL pinning, but as I understand it is for authentication purposes. Should I stick to that or not?

P.S. the URL which will be accessed is not on our Web Server, so we can not manage certificates. For this reason I need to trust it in general in my App.

Comment: I don't think you can do this automatically as installing root certificates without the user's permission would be a huge security flaw. You can try using Apple Configurator/iPhone Configuration Utility to install the needed certificates remotely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot install certificate **inside** app. You can show a guide to tell user how to open and install certificate in Safari. And then open your certificate url in Safari via codes.

Comment: Ok, may be not install but *check* certificate, so I can have normal communication.